# MIN/MAX price for each product (query)

Tags: mysql, sql

### The goal

Select MIN/MAX price of each product in database.

### The problem

I am able to get only products with specified identifiers.

### What I have

I'm using ***MySQL*** and I have the follow query:

```
SELECT (MIN(`map`.`Product_Price`)) as `minProductPrice`,
    (MAX(`map`.`Product_Price`)) as `maxProductPrice`,
    `pr`.`Product_Name` as `productName`
FROM `bm_market_products` as `map`
JOIN `bm_products` as `pr`
JOIN `bm_markets` as `ma`
WHERE `map`.`Product_Id` = 1
AND `map`.`Product_Id` = `pr`.`Product_Id`
```

My return is the `minProductPrice`, `maxProductPrice` and `productName`.

### The solution

Thank you about your help. The both answers above are right — but I chose @GordonLinoff answer's as accepted because I think it will be more useful and enjoyed by beginners — but really thanks to you both guys. **The final query:**

```
SELECT MIN(`map`.`Product_Price`) as `minProductPrice`,
       MAX(`map`.`Product_Price`) as `maxProductPrice`,
       `pr`.`Product_Name` as `productName`
FROM `bm_market_products` `map` join
     `bm_products` as `pr`
     on map`.`Product_Id` = `pr`.`Product_Id`
group by `map`.`Product_Id`
```

Cheers!

Comment: Are you trying to get just the minimum and maximum product price? If so, you can do that by removing the `WHERE map.Product_Id = 1`. Or are you trying to get product information as well - for example the `Product_Id` and/or `ProductName` for the product with the highest price and the `Product_Id` and/or `ProductName` for the product with the lowest price?

Comment: Hello, @EdGibbs. Actually, I'm trying to get the minimum and maximum product price and some information about all items that I have on database.

Comment: Thanks @chiefGui. Also sorry - I missed the cross join that GordonLinoff pointed out below. Either of the two answers here should get you what you need.

Comment: @EdGibbs Sorry? Why? Hehe... You were trying to help me. Thank you about your collaboration anyway. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, when you use `join`, you should *always* have an `on` clause, even though MySQL does not require this.  If you want a `cross join`, then be explicit about it.

Second, you don't use the `tm_markets` table at all in the query.  It is not needed, so remove it.

The resulting query should work:

```
SELECT MIN(`map`.`Product_Price`) as `minProductPrice`,
       MAX(`map`.`Product_Price`) as `maxProductPrice`,
       `pr`.`Product_Name` as `productName`
FROM `bm_market_products` `map` join
     `bm_products` as `pr`
     on map`.`Product_Id` = `pr`.`Product_Id`
WHERE `map`.`Product_Id` = 1
```

Because you are only choosing one product, a `group by` is probably not necessary.  You might consider this, however:

```
SELECT MIN(`map`.`Product_Price`) as `minProductPrice`,
       MAX(`map`.`Product_Price`) as `maxProductPrice`,
       `pr`.`Product_Name` as `productName`
FROM `bm_market_products` `map` join
     `bm_products` as `pr`
     on map`.`Product_Id` = `pr`.`Product_Id`
group by `map`.`Product_Id`
```

That will return the information for all products.

Comment: Wow! Thank you about your answer, dear friend — very useful to me. Thanks thanks thanks! +1 / accepted!

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT (MIN(`map`.`Product_Price`)) as `minProductPrice`,
    (MAX(`map`.`Product_Price`)) as `maxProductPrice`,
    `pr`.`Product_Name` as `productName`,
    `map`.`Product_Id` 
FROM `bm_market_products` as `map`
JOIN `bm_products` as `pr`
JOIN `bm_markets` as `ma`
WHERE `map`.`Product_Id` = `pr`.`Product_Id`
GROUP BY `map`.`Product_Id`
```

Comment: Hey, Joe! Your answer worked well for me and I gave to you +1, but I accepted the @GordonLinoff's answer because it is more complete for beginners. Anyway, thank you so much! +1 :D