# codeigniter select min and max product price from multy tables

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I need to select all (*) the rows from products, prices.. but I need to select the MIN and MAX price from prices. I've read up on how to do this, but how do I do this within an INNER JOIN

this is my build_query() function:

```
 //build sql query string
public function build_query($type = "active")
{
    $select = "products.*,

        (SELECT CONCAT(price) FROM prices WHERE products.id = prices.product_id ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1) AS price;}
```

and this is my products_maxmin_price() function:

```
public function get_shops_products_maxmin_price($parent_id)
{
    $this->build_query();
    $this->db->select('MAX(price) as p_max, MIN(price)  p_min ');
    $this->db->where('products.parent_id', clean_number($parent_id));
    return $this->db->get('products')->result();
}
```

and this is my view:

```
<?php foreach ($shops_products_maxmin_price as $item): ?>
                         <?php echo $item->p_min; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; endif; ?>

<?php foreach ($shops_products_maxmin_price as $item): ?>
                         <?php echo $item->p_max; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Why do you store prices in a separated table?

Comment: Because we need price history, one product with some price in same dates

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the raw query

Answer (score -1):

Try this query below:

```
SELECT MIN(`prices`.`price`) as `p_min`,
       MAX(`prices`.`price`) as `p_max`,
       `products`.*
FROM `prices`
JOIN `products`
ON `prices`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
WHERE `products`.`parent_id` = `<PARENT_ID>`
GROUP BY `prices`.`product_id`;
```

I modify an answer from this question: [MIN/MAX price for each product (query)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025457/min-max-price-for-each-product-query)

**UPDATE:**
Transform the query into Codeigniter Query Builder, and combine your 2 function into 1:

```
public function get_shops_products_maxmin_price($parent_id)
{
    $this->db->select_min('prices.price','p_min');
    $this->db->select_max('prices.price','p_max');
    $this->db->select('products.*');
    $this->db->join('products', 'prices.product_id = products.id');
    $this->db->where('products.parent_id', clean_number($parent_id));
    $this->db->order_by('prices.created_at','DESC');
    $this->db->group_by('prices.product_id');
    return $this->db->get('products')->result();
}
```

Comment: error : Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$p_min

Comment: This is only an SQL query! Not try to running with PHP! I tried to help you to found the right query to your problem. You need to transform this query to your code, because I (we) don't know your environment details

Comment: I am a beginner, could not use your query in the codeigniter, Please apply in my functions if you can

Comment: Then you would have to learn the basics first and only then deal with more serious projects

Comment: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN `products` ON `prices`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` WHERE `products`.`par' at line 2

SELECT MIN(`prices`.`price`) AS `p_min`, MAX(`prices`.`price`) AS `p_max`, `products`.* JOIN `products` ON `prices`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` WHERE `products`.`parent_id` = 1 GROUP BY `prices`.`product_id` ORDER BY `prices`.`created_at` DESC

Comment: Ops, I forget the FROM. Updated the function above

Comment: Error Number: 1066

Not unique table/alias: 'products'

SELECT MIN(`prices`.`price`) AS `p_min`, MAX(`prices`.`price`) AS `p_max`, `products`.* FROM `products` JOIN `products` ON `prices`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` WHERE `products`.`parent_id` = 1 GROUP BY `prices`.`product_id` ORDER BY `prices`.`created_at` DESC